# Cannot connect to Postgresql on port 5432 But can connect on port 5433

Tags: postgresql

I have PostgreSQL 13 installed on a server running Debian 10 Server. When I want to connect my PostgreSQL server, I should connect on port 5433, because my postgresql.conf file is like this:

> ```
> # - Connection Settings -
> listen_addresses = '*' 
> port = 5433   
> max_connections = 100
> unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql'
> ```

But along with this port, I can connect on port 5432. While there is no any config file in my /etc/postgresql/13/main directory that contains port 5432. In addition, `netstat -na` outputs is like this:

For port 5432:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN     
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     27587    /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

For port 5433:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5433            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp      164      0 192.168.1.100:42766     192.168.1.100:5433      CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp      164      0 192.168.1.100:42782     192.168.1.100:5433      CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp6       0      0 :::5433                 :::*                    LISTEN     
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     27607    /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433
```

That is so amazing that I have two different databases on two different ports, When I run `psql` command on 5432 and 5433 ports. I can connect from remote machine on port 5433, but I cannot connect on port 5432 from remote machine and just connect locally.

I want to know where is the port 5432 config and How I change it for remote machine connection?

Comment: Did you install any other version of PostgreSQL?

Comment: Yes. I have PostgreSQL 12 along with PostgreSQL 13.

Comment: Your postgresql 12 has run on port 5432 and postgresql 13 on port 5433.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. My PostgreSQL 12 was on port 5432.